# How to search by object id from the font-end

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, objectid

I have this collection called meals and there's this document:

```json
# Meals collection
{
   name: "burger",
   tag: ObjectId(63d6bb22972f5f2fa97f1506),
}
```

Now I'm inside my React app, and I want to send a query to the backend API of mine,

so I made a request which looks *basically* as follows:

```js
const tagId = "63d6bb22972f5f2fa97f1506"
const queryString = `http://localhost:3001/v1/meals?tag=${tagId}`
sendQuery(queryString)
```

This query is made to the server, and it looks as follows. Following the RESTful pattern:

```
http://localhost:3001/v1/meals?tag=63d6bb22972f5f2fa97f1506
```

On the back-end, I am passing the search parameters as follows:

```js
// # nodejs server-side
// # using expressjs
// # and using mongoose
api.get('/meals', async (req, res, next)=> {
 const res = await MealModel.find(req.query) // req.query = { tag: "63d6bb22972f5f2fa97f1506" }
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success'
    data: res
  })
})
```

However, the query returns nothing, `[]`,

because the `tag` type is actually an object ID, and not a string,

The `req.query.tag` is a string and not an object ID.

How to send an object ID from the front-end to the back-end through JSON?

Sounds crazy, right? What's the solution to this?

Comment: I'm afraid to say there's no way to do it, unfortunately, it's critical to have such a feature, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation regarding this

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

api.get('/meals', async (req, res, next)=> {
 const response = await MealModel.find({tag:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.tag)})
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success'
    data: response
  })
})
```

and if there is only one document in your Meals collection then use findOne, your query will execute faster. Do tell me if it worked. Hope it helps.

Comment: Good but there could be a better way to do it, instead of me having to write `req.query.tag` in all the other routes where I have the field type ObjectId, I want the flow to go straight forward,